# Installing Boost_1_81_0 failing

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, boost

Hey so I'm trying to install the boost library for Windows, I am using Mingw GCC as my compiler and whenever I run my `.\b2 --toolset=gcc --link=shared` after a little while when -compiler supports AVX2 is finished it throws an error stating "Recursion in main target references".

I followed the guide on the installing for windows page.
I also tried to install an older version of boost (1_80_0) but encountered the same error, my friend who is also trying to do the same experences the same issues as me.

There seem to be several things wrong with the whole install process, when I installed b2 into a folder I was asked to add INSTALLPATH/bin to my path even though bin was not a folder within that folder, furthermore whats the point of installing b2 when b2 already exists when I run bootstrap.

Here is a snippet of the output running `.\b2 --toolset=gcc --link=shared` when it fails.

```
    - cxx11_defaulted_functions : no [10]
    - cxx11_final              : no [10]
    - cxx11_hdr_mutex          : no [10]
    - cxx11_hdr_tuple          : no [10]
    - cxx11_lambdas            : no [10]
    - cxx11_noexcept           : no [10]
    - cxx11_nullptr            : no [10]
    - cxx11_rvalue_references  : no [10]
    - cxx11_template_aliases   : no [10]
    - cxx11_thread_local       : no [10]
    - cxx11_variadic_templates : no [10]
    - native atomic int32 supported : no [9]
    - has message compiler     : no [9]
    - native syslog supported  : no [9]
    - pthread supports robust mutexes : no [9]
    - has_icu builds           : no [9]
    - compiler supports SSSE3  : no [9]
    - compiler supports AVX2   : no [9]
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/build\targets.jam:617: in start-building from module targets
error: Recursion in main target references
error: the following target are being built currently:
error: ./forward -> ./stage -> ./stage-proper -> ***libs/filesystem/build/stage*** -> libs/filesystem/build/stage-dependencies -> libs/log/build/stage -> libs/log/build/stage-dependencies -> ***libs/filesystem/build/stage***
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/build\targets.jam:784: in class@main-target.generate from module object(main-target)@8794
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/boost_install\boost-install.jam:1213: in generate-dependencies from module boost-install
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/kernel\modules.jam:106: in modules.call-in from module boost-install
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/util\indirect.jam:105: in indirect.call from module indirect
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/tools\generate.jam:59: in construct from module object(generated-target-class)@4004
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/build\targets.jam:1401: in class@basic-target.generate from module object(generated-target-class)@4004
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/build\targets.jam:820: in generate-really from module object(main-target)@11563
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/build\targets.jam:792: in class@main-target.generate from module object(main-target)@11563
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/build\targets.jam:942: in targets.generate-from-reference from module targets
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/build\targets.jam:1285: in generate-dependencies from module object(alias-target-class)@4005
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/build\targets.jam:1359: in class@basic-target.generate from module object(alias-target-class)@4005
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/build\targets.jam:820: in generate-really from module object(main-target)@11564
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/build\targets.jam:792: in class@main-target.generate from module object(main-target)@11564
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/boost_install\boost-install.jam:1213: in generate-dependencies from module boost-install
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/kernel\modules.jam:106: in modules.call-in from module boost-install
D:/boost/boost_1_80_0/tools/build/src/util\indirect.jam:105: in indirect.call from module indirect
```

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the full error message as formatted text?

Comment: "I feel like I'm missing somthing here." - So do we. Your *code*.

Comment: msys2 has boost binary packages for x64 MinGW 12.2: [https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-boost](https://packages.msys2.org/base/mingw-w64-boost)

Comment: It seems like the error message "Recursion in main target references" has been mentioned in [several issues on their GitHub repository](https://github.com/boostorg/build/issues?q=Recursion+in+main+target+references). I'd recommend going through them, and maybe opening a new one there if you believe this to be a bug in their software.

Comment: @JesperJuhl This question is about an error that occured when building Boost, not when building OP's own code, so I don't think that OP has to include code in the question.

Comment: @kotatsuyaki Okay, I'll post my question on the issues on their github. I am using GCC 12.2.0 (The most recent version) so that might be the issue, not sure.

Answer (score 0):

.\b2 --build-type=complete gcc stage **architecture=x86 address-model=64**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).